# Anti-join dataframes in list to original prior dataframe using `accumulate`

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a list of dataframes, `a`, `b`, and `c`. I want to end up with a list where `a` will not be changed, `b` will contain only those rows not in `a`, and `c` will contain only those rows not in `b`.

```
# Sample data
a <- data.frame(num = 1:4, let = letters[1:4])
b <- data.frame(num = 2:6, let = letters[2:6])
c <- data.frame(num = 3:8, let = letters[3:8])

dfs <- list(a, b, c)
```

The part that's tripping me up is that I need to do the anti_join on the *original* prior dataframe, not the one created after the anti-join to its prior dataframe. My instinct is to use `accumulate` from `purrr` to do this, but I can't figure out how to get it to work on the original prior dataframe.

```
dfs |> 
  accumulate(~anti_join(.y, .x))

[[1]]
  num let
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   3   c
4   4   d

[[2]]
  num let
1   5   e
2   6   f

[[3]]
  num let
1   4   d
2   7   g
3   8   h
```

Since this joins on the already joined prior dataframe, I have `4 d` in the 3rd df which I do not want.

I have tried `.dir = "backward"` as a way to use the original dfs for joining, but that is not doing what I think it should be doing:

```
dfs |> 
   accumulate(~anti_join(.y, .x), .dir = "backward")

[[1]]
  num let
1   7   g
2   8   h

[[2]]
  num let
1   7   g
2   8   h

[[3]]
  num let
1   4   d
2   5   e
3   6   f
4   7   g
5   8   h
```

Is there an way to set the arguments for `accumulate` so it can do this, or will I need a different approach? I prefer purrr/tidyverse if possible but am open to anything that does what I need.

Expected output:

```
[[1]]
  num let
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   3   c
4   4   d

[[2]]
  num let
1   5   e
2   6   f

[[3]]
  num let
1   7   g
2   8   h
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output too?

Comment: I just did. If more sample data would be helpful I can do that too. I realize I really minimized the sample here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accumulate2` instead to implement a rolling `anti_join`.

```r
accumulate2(dfs, head(dfs, -1), ~ anti_join(..2, ..3))
```

```
[[1]]
  num let
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   3   c
4   4   d

[[2]]
  num let
1   5   e
2   6   f

[[3]]
  num let
1   7   g
2   8   h
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** With `map2`:

```r
dfs[-1] <- map2(dfs[-1], dfs[-length(dfs)], anti_join)
```

```r
[[1]]
  num let
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   3   c
4   4   d

[[2]]
  num let
1   5   e
2   6   f

[[3]]
  num let
1   7   g
2   8   h
```

---

`accumulate` is made for dynamic sequencing, here you need one anchor, `df[[1]]`, and a function to apply to the rest of the elements of the list:

```r
dfs[-1] <- map(dfs[-1], ~ anti_join(.x, dfs[[1]]))
```

Comment: I mistyped one letter at the beginning of my question (fixed now). `c` should contain only the rows in `b`. With more dfs it would continue on so `d` would contain only the rows not in `c`, etc. So I am going for dynamic sequencing.

Comment: Check edit, you can use `map2`